# How we can sync on premise active directory data with Azure AD via graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are having on premise employee directory and now planning to move to Azure AD. How we can sync the details of all employees to Azure using graph API, and provide them access to hardware and network.

We basically want to sync Entries, Computer, user, Group, InetOrgPerson, OU present in local AD to Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

Graph REST API which details how to do the sync operation is provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/synchronization-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: thanks a lot Srinath. I will explore this.

I was thinking to plan my migration work by using below mapping and directly doing ReST calls using graph API.We basically moving all our infra related resource to Azure as first step. We have lot of resources like:
- Employess -> I believe this could be mapped to User object in graph
- Computers -> I believe this could be mapped to Device object in graph
- OU are not supported in Azure AD - Will Adminstrative Unit suffice it?
- Groups - Could be mapped with groups object in graph

Comment: I have not tested with the mappings that is pointed here but guess it should work. Will be interested to know the details.